# My English teacher says "I bought a car to my sister" means that my sister sold me a car. Is that sentence grammatically correct?

Tags: prepositions, learning

My English teacher was trying to explain the difference between "I bought a car for my sister" and "I bought a car to my sister", but I don't think the latter is correct. By the way, my English teacher is not a native English speaker. Am I wrong?

Comment: “*to* my sister” is way off; if you want to say your sister sold you a car, you’d want to replace “to” with “from” (or, more in the vernacular, “off”). But if you want a detailed analysis of why, please ask on our sister site, [ell.se].

Comment: de mi hermana would be: I bought the car from my sister. para mi hermana is for my sister. to is just wrong. I sold my car to my sister.

Comment: One way to fix this mess is: I **brought** a car for my sister" and "I **brought** a car to my sister.

Comment: You're right. You cannot buy something to someone.

Answer (score 3):

The construction "bought [a car] [to somebody]" is not idiomatic. It doesn't really have a meaning.

It is idiomatic to say "I bought a car *from* my sister", which means that your sister sold you a car.

This is because "bought" implies that the object comes towards the buyer. But sold means it goes away. So you say "The car comes from Spain" but "I am going to Spain" (and usually not "going from Spain" or "comes to Spain")  And you say "I bought the car from my sister" or "My sister sold the car to me."